# How to get both UV maps to show up

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, game-engine

I'm new here. For the past week I've been trying to replicate my town's fire engine in blender, and all is going well. When I finish I will import the model into a game called emergency 4. However, I had to make 2 UV maps for the model, one for the front half and one for the back half as I could not fit everything on one. The problem is that I don't know how to get both UV maps to show up in blender. If I select the first UV map then only the front half of the fire engine is textured, and if I select the second UV map then only the second half of the fire engine is textured. This is shown below. My question is how do I get both to be selected and show at the same time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you clicked the "assign" button on both on your uv maps?

Answer (score 0):

I believe thts a problem with the UV Map itself u probally need to remap and divide the seams cutting the truck in half first.

Answer (score 0):

You are using blender game engine and also after this project install the new version of blender[image]

Comment: While this answer is not incorrect, it is lacking in explanation. Other users looking this up in the future would benefit from you actually telling why he should switch to another render engine.

Comment: I agree with Ben here. One sentence is a comment but not an answer. Take a look at some of the [top questions and answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), this is what Blender Stackexchange is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution but probably enough if you are only going to do this for one object:
First create a third UV map where the front part and back part are on seperated places on the uv map.
then paint the front part with pure white and the back part with pure black, we are going to use it for blending later on.
Add two uv nodes.
The UV node lets you specify which UV map to use.
Then add two image texture nodes, connect the uv node with the respective image nodes containing front and back part textures.
Then add another uv node and image texture node with the uv set to the third map and the newly created black and white image.
Combine both images with a rgb mix node set to mix.
Use the third image texture  nodes output as the mix factor, if the result is completely black use an invert node on between the third image texture node and the mix rgb factor.

If you were using a newer version of blender I would recommend the use of UDIM's, but for your blender version this stop gap solution should suffice